# Cocoa .scrollToEndOfDocument stops working after 1st try

Tags: swift, cocoa, webkit

I'm writing a small MacOS program with a WebView which loads a website. This is one of those sites that auto loads more content when you scroll to the bottom. As an expirement, I'm trying to write code that will constantly scroll to the bottom of the page so that more of it is loaded and so on.

What I have so far is this:

```
scrollToBottomTotalTimes = 10
self.myWebView.mainFrame.load(NSURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: urlString)! as URL) as URLRequest!)

func webView(_ sender: WebView!, didFinishLoadFor frame: WebFrame!) {

        var scrollToBottomCurrentTimes = 0
        while scrollToBottomCurrentTimes != scrollToBottomTotalTimes {
            scrollToBottomCurrentTimes += 1
            self.myWebView.scrollToEndOfDocument(self)
            sleep(2) //give the page some time to load
        }
}
```

This works well once: The page loads, it scrolls to the bottom, and more of the page loads.

However after that, the WebView doesn't scroll anymore, despite ample time for the page to reload. The position on the page stays exactly as before.

I get the feeling that `.scrollToEndOfDocument(self)` doesn't seem to detect the fact that the webpage has become longer.

Is there a way to 'update' `.scrollToEndOfDocument(self)` so it knows where the new bottom of the page is?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are using a wrong approach. Assuming that new content arrives you may get multiple requests to `didFinishLoadFor`. However you are doing a loop inside the method with a sleep inside the method which makes that you block the main queue and disable the event mechanism.

I suggest you setup a timer event using `Grand Central Dispatch` (`GCD`) and then fire off the scroll event from the timer event. Please note that you have to do the scrolling in the main queue and the timer event is not in the main queue. Just check out the documentation on `GCD`. See https://developer.apple.com/reference/dispatch.